# Python 3: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the __repr__ of a list

Tags: python

I needed a tree data structure in Python copied it from a website and ran into some really strange issues.

If you create an object with two arguements it works, if you use only one argument it fails at print with

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the
>   repr of a list

I understand the error, but it is not clear where and why it happens. The code should also work using the default parameter. I know it is mutable.

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, children = []):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.value)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level+1)
        return ret

    def add(self, value):
        self.children.append(node(value))

#tree = node([1,4,3], [node([2,5,3])]) <-- works
tree = node([1,4,3]) # <-- fails
tree.add([3,4,3])
tree.add([4,4,3])

print(tree)
```

Comment: Try changing `self.children = children` to `self.children = children[:]`

Answer (score 5):

You had a mutable object in your default argument

```
    def __init__(self, value, children = []):
```

This results in a single list instance for `children`, so when you constructed the second list your list of children is then added to that default list thus *every* iteration will traverse inside that list, causing this infinite loop.

You should do something like this

```
    def __init__(self, value, children=None):
        self.value = value
        if children is None:
             children = []
        self.children = children
```

Alternatively you can just

```
        self.children = children or []
```

Both assigns a new list instance which will remove this problem.